# Recommended data model and data source for a Spring MVC website administration / configuration page?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, web-config, administration

I am interested in having a web configuration/admin page for a website.

- Is it more common to store a websites
  configuration in a database, xml, or
  .properties files?
- What does the data model (classes)
  usually look like?
- If stored in a file, is concurrent
  access typically handled and how?
- Are there any good examples for a
  generic site administration page for
  spring java?

Answer (score 0):

Putting config data in the database is a bit messy, but there's some good info here on how to do it:

[How do you structure config data in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240428/how-do-you-structure-config-data-in-a-database)

I wouldn't write to .properties or .xml files for config data - it is a bit confusing as these are typically only used for readonly configuration.